# Add items to Implicitly-typed Arrays of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using an rest service where one of the parameters is an implicitly-typed Arrays of objects

initializing the parameter goes like this:

```
     var values= new[] { new { oval = "123" }, new { oval = "456" } };
```

How do i add new values to the array from a List

Comment: `values = values.Concat(list.Select(item => new { oval = item })).ToArray();`?

Comment: What do mean? Arrays have a constant size, the only way to add elements is create a bigger array, copy the old values and add the new ones.

Comment: @Magnetron is exactly right. Maybe you should be using a List of objects?

Comment: Used itsme86 example. Didnt need to initialize the array 


        List<string> messageRecipients;
        var recipientsT = messageRecipients.Select(item => new { oval = item }).ToArray();